# How to fix "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: firebase, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I want to fetch data from firebase realtime database before rendering the page, I'm using vuex store to handle all my data.

**store/index.js**

```
state: {
      loadedPosts: []
    },
    mutations: {
      setPosts(state, posts) {
        state.loadedPosts = posts;
      },

    },
    actions: {
      nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
        return axios
          .get("https://new-nuxt-blog.firebaseio.com/posts.json")
          .then(res => {
            const postsArray = [];
            for (const key in res.data) {
              postsArray.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key });
            }
            vuexContext.commit("setPosts", postsArray);
          })
          .catch(e => context.error(e));
      },
      setPosts(vuexContext, posts) {
        vuexContext.commit("setPosts", posts);
      }
    },
```

but Iam getting an error saying that **RangeError
Maximum call stack size exceeded**

can anyone help me to fix this error, the data Iam trying to get is just this object:

```
{"-Lcq_6OaDEff_FPWoMux":{"author":"Ayman Tarig","content":"new nuxt blog","thumbnailLink":"http://smarterware.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/technology1.jpg","title":"new nuxt blog"}}
```

Comment: please create a reproduction on codesandbox

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code and it worked perfectly - the changes that I did were -

used **separate exports** and **this.$axios**

```
export const state = () => ({
  loadedPosts: []
})

export const mutations = {
  setPosts(state, posts) {
    state.loadedPosts = posts;
  }
}

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {      
    // return this.$axios <----CHANGE I MADE
    // code removed for brevity    
  },
  setPosts(vuexContext, posts) {
    vuexContext.commit("setPosts", posts);
  }
}
```

And it worked perfectly fine - attaching a screenshot of my screen

[image]

Comment: can you give me the full code of the store/index.js ?

Comment: and where to you import axios ?

Comment: @AymanTarig , the above code is same! You have used - this.axios and i have used this.$axios. 
Setup axios as explained here - https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup

Comment: I've used the same setup as explained in the url you've provided but I'm still getting the same error. you can check my store/index.js and nuxt.config.js files in this link https://github.com/Ayman-Tarig/nuxt-errors and tell me what is wrong in them

Comment: I'm using nuxtjs version 2.6.2

Comment: can you give me access to your repo? 
you can clone my repo / or just have a look at it.
https://github.com/siddhartharora02/nuxt-test

Comment: This is my repo - https://github.com/Ayman-Tarig/nuxt-test - you can check it and tell me what is wrong on it

Comment: It works fire on CodeSandbox, here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Ayman-Tarig/nuxt-test .

Comment: replace ```.catch(e => context.error(e));``` with ```context.error({ statusCode: 404 })```